# How to convert full crash dump to mini dump

Tags: crash, bsod, minidumps

I have a Windows 7 BSOD crash dump of almost 900 mb, and I would like to produce a mini dump from it. Is there a tool for that?

Comment: Try to put it in a .7z file (7-zip), you might be able to compress it by a large amount. The memory might contain a lot of zeroes or some kind of repetition which allows it to be compressed a lot. As far as I know I haven't seen such a tool yet...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A dump can be converted with [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

1. Open the full dump
2. `.dump c:\debug\dumps\small.dmp`

You can automate this task by using `cdb` instead of `windbg` and pass commands via the `-c "<command>"` command line switch, e.g.:

```
cdb -c ".dump c:\debug\dumps\small.dmp ; q" -z c:\debug\dumps\big.dmp
```

The `q` ensures that `cdb` quits after re-dumping.

Answer (score 1):

"The resulting MEMORY.DMP file can be quite large.  However most of the contents are zeroed memory, so it should compress (With WinRAR for example.) to a much smaller size.
A one gigabyte memory dump will usually compress down to 100-300 megabytes, which will allow for much easier transfer across the network." from [here](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO31321)